# Error C3867 Multithreading C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm trying to create multiple threads to handle clicking tasks. Now Visual Studio 2015 doesn't display syntax error, however upon compiling I get the error

`C3867 'action::Chrome::click': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

```
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<action::Chrome>chrome(new action::Chrome());
    const std::vector<uint_16>xLocation = { 1155, 1165, 1205, 1245, 1285 };
    std::vector<uint_16>yLocation;

    //Fill yLocation
    //Yada yada, other code

    std::thread task[6];
    for(uint_8 i = 0; i < 6; i++)task[i] = std::thread((chrome->click, xLocation, yLocation[i]));
    for(uint_8 i = 0; i < 6; i++)task[i].join();
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the declaration of `action::Chrome::click`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a pointer to the member function with `&action::Chrome::click`, not `chrome->click`.

If you pass a pointer-to-member-function, the second parameter is supposed to be the object that the function is "called on".

There's also a problem with your parameter list; the extra parentheses mean that you're only passing `yLocation[i]` to the thread's constructor.

Use

```
std::thread(&action::Chrome::click, chrome, xLocation, yLocation[i]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and how to resolve it. Although changing the code to the one you provided, an error occurred with the unique_ptr which was easily fixed by using shared_ptr